# Find rows with same values PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In a table, there are ids with multiple values

```
id|value
--|------
1 |a
1 |b
2 |a
2 |b
3 |a
3 |c
4 |a
5 |a
5 |b
...
```

so how can i select all id's that have the same values as 
1?
What I want should look like this

```
id
--
1
2
5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want *exactly* the same values, you can use a set-based approach:

```
select t.id
from t join
     t t1
     on t.value = t1.value and t1.id = 1
group by t.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t where t.id = 1);
```

Assuming no duplicates, this counts the number of values that matches each id and then checks that there are the same number.

I should admit that the the `string_agg()` approach is also elegant:

```
select id
from (select id, string_agg(value, ',' order by value) as values,
             max(case when id = 1 then string_agg(value, ',' order by value)) over () as values_1
      from t
      group by id
     ) t
where values = values_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using arrays:

```
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t ORDER BY 1) ids
WHERE ARRAY(SELECT value FROM t WHERE id = ids.id ORDER BY 1) =
      ARRAY(SELECT value FROM t WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY 1);
```

This should work even for duplicated and/or NULL values.